# How to convert an 1D double array to a String

Tags: c#, arrays, string, methods, double

i am trying to connvert
double[] v = { 5, 4, -8, 2, 6 };
to a String with a method.
I created an method called ToString(double[] v);
and tried to do it with an foreach loop, but every time i insert a double the console gives out system.double instead of the string.

for university i am only allowed to use convert.toString and no parse and i should use it as a method

Thanks for your support.

Benjamin

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, you're expected to provide the code you've attempted, so please [edit] that into your question

Comment: where is you code?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to use [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0)

```
var myString = string.Join(", ", myDoubles);
```

But if you want to do the same thing yourself it is fairly easy to do:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var myDouble in myDoubles){
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(myDouble)).Append(",");
}
var myString = sb.ToString();
```

If you are not allowed to use stringBuilder either you can just concatenate strings instead, just keep in mind that increases the algorithmic complexity, and is not really something you should do, or even teach as an example.